# Display multiple records from sqlite bank

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-sqlite

I have a dictionary database ready, I want to use it in Xamarin Android. I wrote some codes. But I could not display the search results in the list view, please help me. It is displayed in the text view, but only one record out of several records, please help me.

```
private void Data()
        {
            ICursor selectData = sqliteDB.RawQuery("select * from tbl_wordss where word  like '" + editText1.Text + "' ", new string[] { });
            if (selectData.Count > 0)
            {
                selectData.MoveToFirst();
                do
                {
                    person user = new person();
                    user.id = selectData.GetString(selectData.GetColumnIndex("id"));
                    user.word = selectData.GetString(selectData.GetColumnIndex("word"));
                    user.meaning = selectData.GetString(selectData.GetColumnIndex("meaning"));
                    lstUser.Add(user);
                   
                   

                }
                while (selectData.MoveToNext());
                selectData.Close();
            }
            foreach (var item in lstUser)
            {
               
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)BaseContext.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
                View addView = layoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.activity_main, null);
               
                TextView textView3 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView3);
                textView3.Text = item.meaning;
```

I tried the codes but only one  record is displayed.
For example, if a searched word has 3 meanings, only the first one will be displayed

Comment: You don't show any code that attempts to display multiple records in an android listview. Add to question the listview code that does not work. Also add the `.axml` that defines the listview.

Answer (score 0):

You can troubleshoot the problem from the following aspects:

1.first check if you could get the data list( `lstUser`) normally.

2.After ensuring that the data can be obtained normally,if you want to display the data list, you can use [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/list-view/) or [RecyclerView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/recycler-view/) to display the data.

From the code you posted,I found that you just used a TextView (`textView3`) to display, even if the data is a normal list, if you iterate through the linked list and display it in turn, the data displayed later will overwrite the data displayed earlier. The visual effect is that only one record is displayed.

> foreach (var item in lstUser)
> {
>
> ```
>             LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)BaseContext.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
>             View addView = layoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.activity_main, null);
>            
>             TextView textView3 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView3);
>             textView3.Text = item.meaning;
> ```

Comment: Thank You. So what should I do, please help me